# How to ensure Django generate postgres table schema for "timestamp with time zone" with default "now()"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following django data model

```
class ApiLog(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    ts = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It ends up with database

```
django=# \d+ users_apilog
                                                           Table "public.users_apilog"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('users_apilog_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 name       | text                     |           | not null |                                          | extended |              |
 ts         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                          | plain    |              |
 ip_address | inet                     |           |          |                                          | main     |              |
 user_id    | integer                  |           | not null |                                          | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "users_apilog_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_apilog_user_id_2eb2b1cf" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_apilog_user_id_2eb2b1cf_fk_users_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Since, this table will also be accessed by non-django app. I need to make sure the auto timestamp generation (For column `ts`) is fully handled by postgres, not python.

---

I don't expect to have

```
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 ts         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              |
```

I expect to have

```
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 ts         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()   | plain   |              |
```

---

I had tried other technique like `auto_now=True`, `auto_now_add=True`, ...

But, none of them generate the table schema I want. By using any below, the generated table schema, its `default` column is still empty.

- `default=timezone.now`
- `auto_now=True`
- `auto_now_add=True`

Comment: The `default`s are *not* filled in by the database, but by Django.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django DB level default value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713642/django-db-level-default-value-for-a-column)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah. I know that. I would like to have it filled by database. Is there any way?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: that was *not* BearBrown, BearBrown actually posted a *sensical* duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it is pretty common to use docker these day. I demonstrate how I solve it, based on docker development environment.

### Step 0 : Make sure you had already committed generated `0001_initial.py`

### Step 1 : Generate empty migration file

```
docker-compose run --rm -v %cd%/django:/app -w /app django /app/manage.py makemigrations users --empty -n alter_ts_default_to_now
```

### Step 2 : Use raw SQL in migration file

```
# Generated by Django 2.1 on 2018-08-25 09:27

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE users_apilog ALTER COLUMN ts SET DEFAULT now()",
        )    
    ]
```

### Step 3 : Run migration again

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py makemigrations users

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

echo "yes" | python manage.py collectstatic

exec "$@"
```