# Apply default_value in Django Model to databases

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app connected to a MS SQL database.

When I create a model, there are fields that will be auto-created or fields that have default value, like the ones below.

```py
class PrincipalFlash(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='sys_admin')
```

However, when I take a look at how the table is created in the database, it looks like below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [webapp].[api_principalflash](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [created_at] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [updated_at] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [updated_by] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

It's only saying that these field are just NOT NULL without any default value. Hence, when I write data to this table directly (not via Django Rest API), it asks me the values for these fields.

Do you guys know how to apply default_value from Django model to the database level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not exist in `Django`.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713642/django-db-level-default-value-for-a-column) is about the subject.

And there is an open [ticket 470](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470) about including default values in the SQL schema.

Comment: hi Timothe, thanks for answering. I didn't see that question before posting mine, is there a way to flag my question as a duplicate of that?

Comment: on top of that, do you think I can just modify the column directly at database level? will it cause any bugs on the application side?

Comment: I've flagged it. You can do it just at the bottom of your post : share / edit / follow / flag

Comment: I see no "hardware" problem to add a default at database level. But you will never take advantage : if you do not add it to Django too, Django will raise Error if missed, and if you do, the value will be always set by Django, and the DB default will never occur too.